# Golang can't install package

Tags: linux, go, package, pixel

I'm trying to get package github.com/faiface/pixel by command:

```
go get github.com/faiface/pixel
```

and error appear `package github.com/faiface/pixel: mkdir /tomekz: permission denied.`
When I try:

```
sudo go get github.com/faiface/pixel
```

no error appears, but also there isn't package.
info about golang:

> ```
> GO111MODULE=""  
> GOARCH="amd64"  
> GOBIN=""  
> GOCACHE="/home/tomekz/.cache/go-build"  
> GOENV="/home/tomekz/.config/go/env"  
> GOEXE=""  
> GOFLAGS=""  
> GOHOSTARCH="amd64"  
> GOHOSTOS="linux"  
> GOINSECURE=""  
> GONOPROXY=""  
> GONOSUMDB=""  
> GOOS="linux"  
> GOPATH="/tomekz/go"  
> GOPRIVATE=""  
> GOPROXY="https://proxy.golang.org,direct"  
> GOROOT="/usr/lib/go"  
> GOSUMDB="sum.golang.org"  
> GOTMPDIR=""  
> GOTOOLDIR="/usr/lib/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"  
> GCCGO="gccgo"  
> AR="ar"  
> CC="gcc"  
> CXX="g++"
> CGO_ENABLED="1"  
> GOMOD=""  
> CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"  
> CGO_CPPFLAGS=""  
> CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"  
> CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"  
> CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"  
> PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"  
> GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/tmp/go-build118455577=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches"
> ```

PS: I use manjaro linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GOPATH` should not be set.
That would make `GOPATH` be, by default, `/home/xxx/go`

Right now, it is set to a path which might be owned by root: `/xxx/go`